# How to find logged IP address from SproutForms sent email

Tags: plugin-sproutforms, ip-address

I see in the documentation for Sprout Forms that IP address is recorded for sent emails. Is this the IP address of the person submitting the form or the IP address of the server sending the mail? Is there a way I can see the IP address of a user who submitted a form on my site with Sprout Forms?

https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/email/sent-emails.html#tracking-info

Answer (score 1):

The `ipAddress` of the user submitting the form is stored in the `sproutforms_entries.ipAddress` column.

Right now, you'd have to look in the database or create a custom report to view the data. I've opened an issue to add that data to the default report so it can be seen more easily:
https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-forms/issues/275

You can use [Sprout Reports](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/reports/) to create a custom report integration using Twig, PHP, or MySQL.